# How can you access an array or a list saved in request scope using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, servlets

In my servlet:

```
String[] array = {"apple", "ball", "cat"};
req.setAttribute("myArray", array);
```

In javascript:

```
var x = '${myArray}';
alert(x.length);              //prints 28
alert('${myArray[0]}');       //prints apple
alert(x)                      //prints [Ljava.lang.String;@267c3c78
```

How can I get the array object without using json so I can loop through it? Is my only option json and xml?

Comment: Is <c:forEach> is what you are looking for ?

Comment: Maybe try `req.setAttribute("myArray", Arrays.toString(array));` the last one is using the `String` value of your array, but Java array doesn't override `toString()` from `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `<c:forEach>` but since Java runs on server side, it will only help you to generate plain text that may be used for your JavaScript. By knowing this, you could create a JavaScript string array like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJavaScriptArray = [
        <c:forEach items="${myArray}" var="elem" varStatus="currentStatus">
            "${elem}"
             <c:if test="${not currentStatus.last}">
                 ,
             </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
        ];
</script>
```

Code above not tested yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign array to javascript variable like this

```
<script>
var x = [
  <c:forEach var="item" items="${myArray}" varStatus="loop">
    "${item}"
    <c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
  </c:forEach>
]
<script>
```

or if you want to avoid it , then from server side pass the proper representation of javascript array. `Arrays.toString()` will help.